# How to set image on collection view header

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uicollectionview

I have a `UICollectionViewController` embedded in a navigation controller. I want to set an image on the header of the collection view.

What I have done is:

Created `CollectionHeaderView` class

Placed `UIImageView` on the header and given outlet to `CollectionHeaderView.h` using `storyboard`.

Set class name to `CollectionHeaderView` and identifier name to headerView.

I have used below code to set image for the `UIImageView`

```
- (UICollectionReusableView *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:(NSString *)kind atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

UICollectionReusableView *reusableview = nil;

if (kind == UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader) {
    CollectionHeaderView *headerView = [collectionView dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind:UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader withReuseIdentifier:@"headerView" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    UIImage *headerImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"header_banner.png"];
    headerView.backgroundImage.image = headerImage;

    reusableview = headerView;
}
return reusable view;
}
```

Comment: did u try this http://www.appcoda.com/supplementary-view-uicollectionview-flow-layout/ ?

Comment: Thanks Mr. T for editing the question. I have checked the link and found my mistake. I have posted that in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Self Answer**

The `CollectionHeaderView.h` file needs to be imported in the `CollectionViewController.m` file. That is where `viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind` method should be implemented.